# generate css classes with same content

Tags: css, sass

I have the below sass. In it I am have several charx classes, where x is between 1...7. is it possible to define them in a more concise way instead of defining each one of them individually ?

```
$first-color: #666666;
$second-color: #0066CC;

@mixin letter($color){
    color: $color;
}


.char1{
    @include letter($first-color);
}

.char2{
    @include letter($second-color);
}

.char3{
    @include letter($first-color);
}

.char4{
    @include letter($second-color);
}

.char5{
    @include letter($first-color);
}

.char6{
    @include letter($second-color);
}

.char7{
    @include letter($first-color);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly achieve the same effect with plain CSS:

```
$first-color: red;
$second-color: salmon;

span:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  color: $first-color;
}

span:nth-of-type(2n) {
  color: $second-color;
}
```

Alternatively, your could use the [`@while`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id13) directive:

```
$i: 1;
@while $i <= 7 {
  .char#{$i}{
    @include letter($first-color);
  }

  .char#{$i+1}{
    @include letter($second-color);
  }  

  $i: $i + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `even` and `odd` rules?
Like so you will be able to add infinite elements without touching your css every time.

```
$first-color: #666666;
$second-color: #0066CC;

@mixin letter($color){
      color: $color;
}


.chars div:nth-child(even){
       @include letter($first-color);
}

.chars div:nth-child(odd){
       @include letter($second-color);
}
```

[Here's](http://codepen.io/nobitagit/pen/rckbC) an example on my Codepen.